# Backspace \b escape sequence won't work with multiple print() functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

```
>>> print("x\by")
y

print("a", end="")
print("a", end="")
print("a", end="")
print("h", end="")

aaah
```

But with multiple print statements, I am getting this output -

```
print("a\b", end="")
print("a\b", end="")
print("a\b", end="")
print("h\b", end="")

a a a h
```

Why did it print extra space after each character.

The code works fine when executed from the Windows command line, I tested it in Pycharm's console.

But in python repl, the `\b` erases the previous character while it is supposed to move cursor a character backward.

```
>>> print("a\b", end="")
>>>
```

Comment: Your update doesn't erase the character. The next `>>>` prompt *overwrites it*.

Comment: Try `print("a\b\n", end="")` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each terminal or console is free to handle the `\b` character differently. All Python can do is write out the data to `sys.stdout`.

Here, the console you are using will move the cursor onwards for separate write calls, it appears. And the `\b` character doesn't erase anything in the console, it merely moves the cursor back a spot *within the same write call*.

So for `print('x\by', end='')` the console outputs `x`, moves back a step, outputs `y` in the same place, and now has recorded that it wrote 3 characters, so the output position is set to column 3. The next `print()` will start outputting data *from that new position*.

Your `print()` code happens to work on most terminals or consoles, because most of those don't care about how many characters you output, only where the cursor currently has been positioned. But that you have a console that behaves differently is *not Python's fault*.

When using the Python interactive interpreter, take into account that *it too* prints; so using `print("a\b", end="")` leaves Python to then overwrite the line with the next `>>>` prompt:

```
>>> print("a\b", end="")
>>>
```

Use `print("a\b\n", end="")` instead and you'll see the `a` is still there:

```
>>> print("a\b\n", end="")
a
```

Answer (score 0):

flush = True is the correct answer in this case

---

If you actually print in the python console then the flush argument first prints out the result and then finishes the function. In the case of multiple escape characters you should see the backspace or any other printed out. The why it happens is not known to me since I am just starting in Python but after thorough research and experimentation i have found it to be true.

Comment: is flush = True the same as `sys.stdout.flush()`?

Answer (score -2):

Write in the end

```
Flush=true
```

I think this is the problem try and write here what output will had because now i can't test it.(Write from phone)